# How to get maximum values of sine function with offset per row_number

Tags: trigonometry, azure-data-explorer, timeserieschart, argmax

Well, I have defined this query:

```
range Value from 1 to 360 * 50 step 25
| extend n=row_number()
| extend x=sin(radians(Value)) * 100 + n
| where x >= 0
| project-away n
| render columnchart
```

Which defines the following chart:

[image: ...]

I want to summarize it in some way that I get points on this line:

[image: ...]

You see there the line I mention with the points (I only set some of them, because there are a lot to paint)

This is what I need.